# Is it possible to install jre6 using brew or sdkman?

Tags: java, homebrew, java-6, sdkman

Is it possible to install jre6 using brew or sdkman? I tried:

```
$ brew install jre6
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "jre6"

$ brew install java6
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

$ sdk list java
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
 Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AdoptOpenJDK  |     | 12.0.1.j9    | adpt    |            | 12.0.1.j9-adpt
               |     | 12.0.1.hs    | adpt    |            | 12.0.1.hs-adpt
               |     | 11.0.3.j9    | adpt    |            | 11.0.3.j9-adpt
               |     | 11.0.3.hs    | adpt    |            | 11.0.3.hs-adpt
               |     | 8.0.212.j9   | adpt    |            | 8.0.212.j9-adpt
               |     | 8.0.212.hs   | adpt    |            | 8.0.212.hs-adpt
 Amazon        |     | 11.0.3       | amzn    |            | 11.0.3-amzn
               |     | 8.0.212      | amzn    |            | 8.0.212-amzn
               |     | 8.0.202      | amzn    |            | 8.0.202-amzn
 Azul Zulu     |     | 12.0.1       | zulu    |            | 12.0.1-zulu
               |     | 11.0.3       | zulu    |            | 11.0.3-zulu
               |     | 10.0.2       | zulu    |            | 10.0.2-zulu
               | >>> | 9.0.7        | zulu    | installed  | 9.0.7-zulu
               |     | 8.0.212      | zulu    |            | 8.0.212-zulu
               |     | 8.0.202      | zulu    |            | 8.0.202-zulu
               |     | 7.0.222      | zulu    |            | 7.0.222-zulu
               |     | 7.0.181      | zulu    |            | 7.0.181-zulu
 Azul ZuluFX   |     | 11.0.2       | zulufx  |            | 11.0.2-zulufx
               |     | 8.0.202      | zulufx  |            | 8.0.202-zulufx
 BellSoft      |     | 12.0.1       | librca  |            | 12.0.1-librca
               |     | 11.0.3       | librca  |            | 11.0.3-librca
               |     | 8.0.212      | librca  |            | 8.0.212-librca
 GraalVM       |     | 19.0.2       | grl     |            | 19.0.2-grl
               |     | 19.0.0       | grl     |            | 19.0.0-grl
               |     | 1.0.0        | grl     |            | 1.0.0-rc-16-grl
 Java.net      |     | 14.ea.3      | open    |            | 14.ea.3-open
               |     | 13.ea.27     | open    |            | 13.ea.27-open
               |     | 12.0.1       | open    |            | 12.0.1-open
               |     | 11.0.2       | open    |            | 11.0.2-open
               |     | 10.0.2       | open    |            | 10.0.2-open
               |     | 9.0.4        | open    |            | 9.0.4-open
 SAP           |     | 12.0.1       | sapmchn |            | 12.0.1-sapmchn
               |     | 11.0.3       | sapmchn |            | 11.0.3-sapmchn
================================================================================
Use the Identifier for installation:

    $ sdk install java 11.0.3.hs-adpt
```

I am trying to run JarInspector app at http://www.codeland.org/

Thank you.

Comment: Probably not, given that JRE 6 is well beyond its end of life.

Comment: As @Makoto said, it's beyond end of life. It doesn't have any support nor any security updates. What would you like to do? What is your scenario?

Comment: @ManuelPolacek does the scenario matter? This could simply be a legacy project.

Comment: @Andronicus yes, it does... There are many different ways to solve a problem. In example, if it is an old web application, you could let it run sandboxed in a docker container, that your underlying system cannot be attacked. Scenario always matters to improve implementation and options. If you know the software, maybe there is an alternative one. The more you know the better options you get.

Comment: @Andronicus One could read this request as "tell me the resource to install java 6 on macos", which renders it off topic immediately. Then the question should at least make a good point why it is nonetheless relevant. You dont need an old java to run an old application. You dont need an old jre to develop for an old java (sure, the build env needs the right jdk, but for source code editing on your dev machine, you can always force the IDE to allow only older syntax).

Comment: I found it here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US &  https://updates.cdn-apple.com/2018/macos/031-33898-20171026-7a797e9e-b8de-11e7-b1fe-c14fbda7e146/javaforosx.dmg

Comment: I am trying to run JarInspector app at http://www.codeland.org/ - it was last updated in 2007.

Answer (score 2):

The following instructions helped me to install jdk6:

```
$ brew tap caskroom/versions
$ brew cask install java6

$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```

Comment: brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install homebrew/cask-versions/java6

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/java6
```

Comment: I believe it's brew install homebrew/cask-versions/java6

Comment: @TravisSchneeberger is right, looks like when i try `brew cask`, it says that it's no longer a brew command

Answer (score 1):

Update 03-2022, OSX Monterey
We can install with brew and add manually to sdkman:

```
brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/java6

$ cd ~/.sdkman/candidates/java
$ ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/ 1.6.0.jdk
$ sdk use java 1.6.0.jdk
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```